# pgfplotstable as pmatrix

Tags: pgfplotstable

The content of the file matrix.dat is:

```
11 12 13 14  
21 22 23 24
31 32 33 34
```

What I want is a rendering in LaTeX like this:

```
/ 11 12 13 14 \
| 21 22 23 24 |
\ 31 32 33 34 /
```

I can load the file with pgfplotstable and render it as pmatrix.

```
\pgfplotstableread{data/matrix.dat}\mytable
\pgfplotstabletypeset[
  begin table=\begin{pmatrix},
  end table=\end{pmatrix},
  skip coltypes,
  display columns/0/.style={string type},
  write to macro=\mymatrix,
  typeset=false
]{\mytable}
$\mymatrix$
```

But what I get is:

```
/  0  1  2  3 \
| 11 12 13 14 |
| 21 22 23 24 |
\ 31 32 33 34 /
```

I could not find an option in pgfplotstable to skip the head row (and not a data row). In pgfplots there is an option

```
\addplot file[skip first] {datafile.dat};
```

What can I do?

There is a related posting dealing with a multicolumn header for pgfplotstable lacking a solution: http://old.nabble.com/pgfplotstable%3A-multicolumn-header-td28329964.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For this, you should use the option `header=has colnames` when reading the table. This tells pgfplots to assume the first line of the file to contain the header, even if it consists only of numbers.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{filecontents}{matrix.dat}
11 12 13 14  
21 22 23 24
31 32 33 34
\end{filecontents}

\begin{document}

\pgfplotstableread[header=has colnames]{matrix.dat}\mytable
\pgfplotstabletypeset[
  begin table=\begin{pmatrix},
  end table=\end{pmatrix},
  skip coltypes,
  write to macro=\mymatrix,
  typeset=false
]{\mytable}
$\mymatrix$

\end{document}
```

[image: pmatrix from file]